# TIMESTAMPDIFF producing negative result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an issue with the following TIMESTAMPDIFF (which calculates the time difference between changes of location) producing a negative result but only for the first TIMESTAMPDIFF calculation, thereafter the calculation for each subsequent row is correct, it may be that the IFNULL expression is incorrect –

```
SELECT 
    assetID
    , nodeid
    , @changed := IF(nodeid <> previousLocationID, @changed + 1, @changed) AS changed
    , IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, previousTs,  ts),  0) AS secDiff

  FROM
    (SELECT 
      assetID
      , nodeid
      , @locationID AS previousLocationID
      , @locationID := nodeid AS currentLocationID
      , ts
      , @ts AS previousTs
      , @ts := ts AS currentTs
    FROM Logs L1
    where assetID LIKE varassetid
    and ts >= vardtmin
    and ts <= vardtmax 
    ORDER BY ts
    ) L2
```

The output (produced by the inner SELECT and simplified to show change of location / nodeid) is correct –

```
assetID nodeid  previousLocationID  currentLocationID   ts  previousTs  currentTs

1569    1   NULL    1   2017-09-04 09:33    NULL    ...


1569    1   NULL    1   2017-09-04 09:40    NULL    ...

1569    2   NULL    2   2017-09-04 09:40    NULL    ...

1569    2   NULL    2   2017-09-04 09:41    NULL    ...

1569    1   NULL    1   2017-09-04 09:41    NULL    ...
```

The output produced by the outer SELECT is –

```
assetID nodeid  changed secDiff

1569    1   NULL    -2676

1569    1   NULL    1

1569    1   NULL    1

1569    1   NULL    3
```

The first secDiff is minus / incorrect (it should be 392 secs (6mins & 32 secs)).

I believe this statement is not working correctly (for the first calculation only) or one of the variables starts in an unknown state -

```
, IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, previousTs,  ts),  0) AS secDiff
```

Changing to -

```
IF(timestampdiff(second, previousTs, ts) < 0, 0, timestampdiff(second, previousTs, ts)) as secDiff
```

eliminates the minus value but results in zero (instead of 392 secs)

I suspect one of the variables starts off in an arbitary state and this causes an issue for the calculation on the first row (where there is no previousTS as such)

Any thoughts?

Comment: you are checking for Null not negative values, try this: ........ if (timestampdiff(second, previous, ts) < 0, 0, timestampdiff(second, previous, ts))

Comment: Thanks Christian, the first calculation now shows as 0 but it should be 392 secs (6mins & 32 secs)

Comment: I am not sure why the incorrect value results in such a value.. can you post the previousTS an its relating ts value?

Comment: previousTS always shows as a NULL in the table (which is bizarre even for a variable) for each record, even though subsequent calculations work. I can only assume that the variable starts off in some unpredictable state. I have modified my original entry

Comment: I think the solution is to ensure that the first iteration of @ts AS previousTS is populated with a 'start datetime' (i.e. vardtmin) but I dont know how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I will continue investigating at a later date